# How do you transform a upn name to a login name?

Tags: .net, ldap, windowsdomainaccount

How do you transform a upn name like "user@example.com" to the corresponding NT account name, which is frequently "EXAMPLE\user"?  In the domains I'm familiar with, I can take the first part after the '@' sign, but I'm concerned that this is not guaranteed to be correct.  Do I have to run an ldap query?  Would it be a property on the user's DirectoryEntry if I did?

I'm trying to do this in C#, but I'd welcome any pointers or corrections to my terminology.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using p-invoke to call [DsCrackNames](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ntdsapi/DsCrackNames.html), rather than using the COM interface Mischa suggested (which I understand is a wrapper around the same function).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the NameTranslateClass of the ActiveDs library which is present in windows.

Look at:
http://www.rlmueller.net/NameTranslateFAQ.htm

It is written for VBScript but you can easily transfer it via interop to c#.

See MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706046(VS.85).aspx